# Angular autocomple undefined issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have used exactly same code mentioned in this fiddle

[autocomplete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/)

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

But for me it is throwing undefined error ( iElement.autocomplete  undefined is not a function ) .I have noticed that above example they have used angular 1.0.0 but i am using angular 1.2.2

I am stuck here ,please suggest

Comment: Did you include the jQuery-UI dependency before AngularJS? This appears to be a dependency order issue.

Comment: yes..any way it is working for me now , i used this http://plnkr.co/edit/t1neIS?p=preview